# Whats happening with this css?

Tags: css

I have some css applied to buttons.

The problem I have is that the rendering changes without me changing the css. It only happens in firefox.

Here's what it should look like:

[image]

Here's what happens from time to time when I post back

[image]

As you can see an extra line is added to the bottom.

Here's the css:

```
.button
{
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.button.nav
{
    background:#999;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(187,187,187,1) 0%, rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(187,187,187,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(153,153,153,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(187,187,187,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(187,187,187,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(187,187,187,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(187,187,187,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%);
    border:solid 1px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px 0 #ddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px 0 #ddd;
    box-shadow:0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),inset 0 1px 0 #ddd;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:13px;
    height:26px;
    line-height:26px;
    text-shadow:#999 0 -1px;
}

.button.nav:hover
{
    background:#777;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(153,153,153,1) 0%, rgba(119,119,119,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(153,153,153,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(119,119,119,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(153,153,153,1) 0%,rgba(119,119,119,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(153,153,153,1) 0%,rgba(119,119,119,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(153,153,153,1) 0%,rgba(119,119,119,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(153,153,153,1) 0%,rgba(119,119,119,1) 100%);
    border-color:#777;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset  0 1px 0 #bbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset  0 1px 0 #bbb;
    box-shadow:0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px 0 #bbb;
    text-shadow:#777 0 -1px;
}
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: As it happens *from time to time* after post backs, I suspect it won't be in CSS posted..

Comment: Is this on a live site we can visit (with firebug)?

Comment: @nelsonic No unforunately its on my development machine.

Comment: works for me every time here - http://jsfiddle.net/Nvau4/  and I've refreshed it around 15 times

Comment: @MichalKlouda - I agree Michael. When I say postback, this is merely a refresh rather than doing some other processing.

Comment: @ZoltanToth - I'm using Fireox 16.0.1 - this may be the problem, I only have access to IE8 at the moment other than Firefox, which wont render most of that css anyway.

Comment: @ZoltanToth - Ive just tested your fiddle and it works, although the numbers are a little lower than on my machine (maybe thats a clue). The line below which should not be there is color#bbb which co-incidentally is the top shadow for the hover state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer.

[image]

The red is the background container with no height set. The green spans had a line height set equivalent to the height of the buttons, however their alignment would have been set to the default of baseline.

I can do 1 of 2 things. 1) remove the line height (although not tested in IE) or 2) add verical-align:middle;

Thanks to everyone for advice.

Answer (score 0):

try to apply the style button.nav also been visited and active

```
.button.nav, .button.nav:visited, .button.nav:active{
    /* style */
}
```